# How to set ini_get use the right ini file?

Tags: php, php-ini

There are many php.ini files inside our linux ubuntu server. I want to use ini_get in my php file; so how to tell the script to use the right php.ini file ?

Comment: There will be only one _valid_ `php.ini` file associated with your PHP installation, imo.

Comment: What do you mean by "right php.ini file"?

Comment: I mean by "right php.ini file" the file which is used by my php page.

Comment: @pheromix Yes, but why are you talking about the `ini_get` function? It has very little to do with the ini file (aside from getting stuff from it, of course).

Comment: I want to set the value of a variable to `ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime")`. So I want to be sure the ini_get function reads data from the right ini file !

Comment: Note that ini_get is affected by ini_set, whereas [get_cfg_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php) will return the value in the INI file regardless of any runtime changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which `php.ini` file is the used one looking at the output of `phpinfo()`.

See the image at [this blog post](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/hosting/using-linux/tutorials/phpinfo), there's a row saying `Loaded Configuration file`. That's the value you are looking for.

From the command line, you can use:

```
php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
```

From inside php, there's the [`php_ini_loaded_file`](http://php.net/php_ini_loaded_file) function

Comment: but how to know it programmatically ?

Comment: See also [`php_ini_scanned_files`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php), as other files may have been parsed.

Answer (score 1):

please echo phpinfo()

You can find the path of the ini file in it.

Comment: but how to know it programmatically ?